# When is uniform continuity and continuity same ?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Continuous function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-function-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous)

How does uniform continuity and continuity coincide in a Compact set ?

Comment: See this question: [Continuous function on a compact metric space is uniformly continuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-function-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous). Also, you should tell us in what setting are you working: real functions? functions on metric spaces? functions on [uniform spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Generalization_to_uniform_spaces)?

Comment: In fact, the question asked in the title is not the same as in the body. In the last one, we have to see whether a continuous function on a compact space is uniformly continuous, whereas in the title it's asked whether continuity implies uniform continuity. In the case of real-valued functions defined on metric spaces, we can show that a continuous function is uniformly continuous if the metric space is compact, and if each continuous function is uniformly continuous, the metric space is compact without isolated points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity is a local property. On a compact set, you can get global properties by combining a finite number of local properties.

More precisely, continuity means that given $\varepsilon>0$, for each point $x$ there is a $\delta_x>0$ such that points $\delta_x$-near $x$ are sent to points $\varepsilon$-near $f(x)$. In a compact set, you can take a finite number of $\delta_x$ to cover the domain and take $\delta>0$ as the minimum of those and so get a $\delta>0$ that works for all points for the given $\varepsilon$.

PS: I'm using the characterization of compact sets as the ones for which every open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: The minimum of the finitely many $\delta_{x_1},\ldots,\delta_{x_n}$ is not good enough. If $x$ is arbitrary then $x$ is $\delta$-close to some $x_k$. If $d(x,y) \lt \delta$ then there's no guarantee that $y$ is also close to *the same* $x_k$, only to some other $x_l$. So you cannot compare the values $f(x)$ and $f(y)$.

Comment: t.b.'s objection can be worked around using the trick in the answer that [Martin linked to](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137193/when-is-uniform-continuity-and-continuity-same#comment315952_137193)

Comment: @t.b., right, I forgot about the $\delta_x/2$ thing. Thanks.

Comment: @lhf is your answer now correct?