# Proof of uniform continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Show that the function $f(x) = \cfrac{x^2 + 5x - 7}{(x^2 - 9x + 8)(x-2)}$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $(3,5)$ (not with epsilon and delta)

How do I  do this question? I am sitting an exam in an hour, and this is likely similar to one of the questions that is on it. Help please

Comment: Very sneaky question.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-function-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous

Comment: @Nameless Why is it 'sneaky'?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The denominator does not vanish in the interval $[3,5]$. Thus our function is continuous on the closed bounded interval $[3,5]$, and therefore uniformly continuous in that interval. So it is uniformly continuous on $(3,5)$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that

- If $g$ is continuous and its domain is a closed interval $[a,b]$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous (it's a theorem that can be found in Real Analysis books);
- If $g$ is uniformly continuous, then any restriction of $g$ is uniformly continuous (it follows of definition of uniform continuity).

Now, notice that

- the function $g:[3,5]\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x) = \cfrac{x^2 + 5x - 7}{(x^2 - 9x + 8)(x-2)}$ is continuous;
- your function $f$ is a restriction of $g$.