# Direct proof of uniform continuity on compact set

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I've looked in several books for a direct proof of the theorem that says if a function is continuous on a compact set, then it is uniformly continuous. I've only found proofs that argue by contradiction.

Is there a way to prove this directly? In case there is could you please post one or tell me where I can find one please?

Comment: See the first answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-function-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous).