# Why is this function uniformly continuous?

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces, uniform-continuity

Assuming $X$ is a normed space. Why is a function $f:K\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ uniformly continuous on a subspace $K\subset X$, if $K$ is sequentially compact and $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Have you made any progress? What do you know about compactness in a metric space?

Answer (score 2):

Because continuity on a compact is the same as uniform continuity.

Note that sequential compactness is the same as compactness.

[Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-function-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous) a link to a proof.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Prove that if $K, Y$ are metric spaces, with $K$ compact space, then every $f:K\to Y$ continuous is uniformly continuous.