# Uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I want to find an example of a continuos function on an open interval S⊂R, which is not uniform continuos. I use f(x)=1/x on the open interval from (0,1).

But I also want to determine if such examples are possible when S is compact?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? You want a continuous function on a compact set $S$ but... [fill in what you want here to happen (outside of $S$?)].

Comment: Oh guys sorry, i forgot to write uniform continuos. Edited the post now.

Comment: $\sin(1/x)$ will do the trick too on $(0,1)$

Comment: and no, a function continuous on $[a,b]$ is also uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ (same with compacts)

Comment: @AlexR. So I want to determine if there exists continuos functions on an open interval S⊂R, which is not uniform continuos. But this time S is compact.

Comment: @user1952009 Dont you mean the reverse ? Uniform continuity implies continuity?

Comment: no I mean the [wiki/Heine–Cantor_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem) that if $f$ is continuous on a compact then it is uniformly continuous on it

Comment: Okay so if f is continuous on a compact set then this implies that f is uniformly continuous? 
But why is this true? Im not sure if I understand the idea of a compact set to 100%.

Comment: Did you read the proof?  Yes, the idea of a compact set is a little slippery, but it is hugely important if you are going to get anywhere in analysis class.

Comment: Yeah I read the proof, but they use some different notations that im not so used to.

Comment: Any continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous on this set.

Comment: @Masacroso Is there a logical interpretation on why it makes sense? Or visualize it in a way?

Comment: See [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Heine-Cantor_Theorem) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-function-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous).

Answer (score 1):

For example, $\;f(x)=\cfrac1x\;$ is continuous in $\;(0,1)\;$ but not uniformly continuous, because for example

$$\left\{\,\frac1n\,\right\}_{n\ge2}\,,\,\,\left\{\,\frac1{n+1}\,\right\}_{n\ge2}\subset (0,1)\;\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;\left|\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right|=\frac1{n(n+1)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

yet

$$\left|f\left(\frac1n\right)-f\left(\frac1{n+1}\right)\right|=1\rlap{\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Comment: Yeah, this made sense. But is this related to my question on wheter there exists continuos functions on an open interval S⊂R, which is not uniform continuos. But this time S is compact?

Comment: @Biggiez : I answered you..

Comment: For a compact set in a metric space, continuity is uniform continuity.  This follows from alternate definition of compactness (every open cover has a finite subcover).

Comment: @Biggiez First, you were already answered in the comments, as the comment above mentions. Second, that is a theorem: a continuous real function on a closed, bounded (=compact) interval is u.c. there.

Answer (score 0):

Uniform continuity is a tighter definition than regular continuity.  So, if f is uniformly continuous then f is continuous.

However, if f is a continuous function on a compact domain the f is uniformly continuous on the domain.

Proof:

If $f$ is continuous, then the for every open set in the image of $f$, the pre-image is an open set.

That is, for every epsilon ball in the image ($|f(x) - f(y)|<\epsilon$) There is a corresponding delta ball in the pre-image ($|x-y| < \delta$).

We cover image of $f$, in open balls, each of radius $\frac\epsilon2$. Each of those balls has its corresponding delta ball.  The union of these delta balls forms an open cover of the domain.

The domain is compact!  Every open cover has a finite sub-cover.  Choose finitely many many of these delta balls.

If there are finitely many delta balls then there is a minimum radius $\frac\delta2$.

For every $(x,y)$ in the domain within a ball of radius $\frac\delta2, |x-y|<\delta$ everything inside that delta ball maps into a corresponding ball of radius $\frac \epsilon2,  |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: How do you get the radius ϵ/2?

Comment: If f(x) and f(y) are within a ball of radius $\epsilon/2$, the distance between f(x) and f(y) is less than epsilon.