# Is $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, uniform-continuity

Is 
\begin{align*}
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+1}
\end{align*}
uniformly continuous?

I was able to show that $f$ has a global maximum at $f(0,0)=1$, but I can't seem to work out a proper estimate for uniform continuity. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes. This is because its gradient is bounded, so the function is Lipschitz continuous. Another way to prove it is using the fact that it is continuous and $$\lim_{|(x,y)| \to \infty} f(x,y)=0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name $X=(x,y)$. Then

$$f(x,y)=f(X)= \frac{1}{\Vert X\Vert^2 +1}.$$
Where $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ is the Euclidean norm.

We have

$$\begin{aligned}\vert f(X_1)-f(X_2) \vert &= \left\vert \Vert X_1\Vert - \Vert X_2 \Vert\right\vert \left\vert \frac{\Vert X_1\Vert + \Vert X_2\Vert}{(\Vert X_1\Vert +1)(\Vert X_2\Vert +1)}\right\vert\\
&\le 2\left\vert \Vert X_1\Vert - \Vert X_2 \Vert\right\vert\\
&\le 2\Vert X_1 -X_2 \Vert\end{aligned}$$

as $\frac{\Vert X_i\Vert}{(\Vert X_1\Vert +1)(\Vert X_2\Vert +1)} \le 1$ for $i=1,2$ and using reverse triangle inequality.

Which implies uniform continuity.

*Note: we get as a bonus that proof above is valid for any normed space.*

Comment: I believe you are missing some squared terms in your denominator. Other than that I believe I follow your reasoning.

Comment: @Walt You're right! Fortunately the end result still remains as $\frac{\Vert X_i\Vert}{(\Vert X_1\Vert^2 +1)(\Vert X_2\Vert^2 +1)} \le 1$ is also true.

Answer (score 2):

Any continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb R^2$ that satisfies $\lim_{|z|\to \infty}f(z)=0$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-mapping-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\displaystyle \|\nabla f(x,y)\| = 2\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{(x^2+y^2+1)^4}}$ and the function $z\mapsto \frac{z}{(z+1)^4}$ is bounded for non-negative $z$, so $\nabla f$ is bounded and $f$ is Lipschitz, hence uniformly continuous.