# Uniform continuity of piece wise function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-continuity

I want to show that the piece wise function $f(x)=x$ for $0\le x<1$ Or $f(x)=x^3$ for $1\le x\le 2$is uniformly continuous. I can show uniformly continuous on each interval separately but how do I show uniform continuity on of the whole function on the entire interval.

Comment: Every continuous function on a compact interval is uniformly continuous.

Comment: What if I’m not familiar with this theorem? Can I show from definition?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use the definition. Observe that $f$ is continuous map on a compact (or closed and bounded) interval to the real numbers, hence, it must be uniformly continuous. If you are not familiar with this result, you may want to take to a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110573/151611).

Comment: How do I show using definition or at least intuitively for a beginner like me?

Comment: What definition are you talking about?

Comment: @amsmath The uniform continuity definition.

Comment: @Danny If you are trying to prove this by using the definition, you must appeal to Completeness Axiom of some form of other.

Comment: @amsmath I am referring to the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition. Of course, I can easily use this definition to show uniform continuity piecewise but how do I do this for the function on the entire interval?

Comment: We told you how. Look up the corresponding theorem and its proof. Of course, the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition is used in the proof.