# Find a continuous bounded function $f:(0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ that is not uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Find a continuous bounded function $f:(0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ that is not uniformly continuous. Extend $f$ with continuity in such a way that $f(0)=0$ and find the oscillation $\omega _f(0)$ of $f$ at $0$.

I'm not sure if I have to extend the function with continuity, but I think so. I'm struggling to find a function, I've tried $\sin(1/x)$ but can't extend it with continuity. Any hint?

Comment: the unique possibility that you have to find such function is that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ doesn't exists

Comment: The question is wrong. If $f$ extends to a continuous  function on $[0,1]$ then it is necessarily uniformly continuous.

Comment: It isn't possible. If you could extend the function to $[0, 1]$ continuously, then the extended function would be a [continuous function on a compact interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/continuous-mapping-on-a-compact-metric-space-is-uniformly-continuous), which makes it uniformly continuous. If the function is uniformly continuous on $[0, 1]$, then it will be on $(0, 1]$ too.

Comment: (I got uniform continuity and bounded variance confused; mea culpa for my incorrect comment.)

Comment: It isn't a condition that when I extend it it should not be unif. cont., so I think I can take any function that satisfies not unif. cont. on $(0,1]$ and extend it piece-wise with f(0)=0 and compute the oscillation which is an extended real numbers ($+\infty,-\infty$ are in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$), right?

Comment: To repeat the advice of @Masacroso,  translate this to an equivalent problem that does not mention uniform continuity: *Find a continuous, bounded function $f:(0,1]\to\mathbb R$ such that the limit $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x)$ does not exist.*

Comment: I see, it isn't possible that you can extendet it with continuity.

Comment: the topological comb $x\mapsto\sin(x^{-1})$ will do the job. Youncan cook-up several functions like this using periodic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $f(x) = sin(\frac{1}{x})$? Clearly $sin$ is bounded and continuous. As $x$ goes to $0^+$ , $sin(\frac{1}{x})$ will oscillate between -1 and +1.